# How to forward IP between 2 interfaces in ubuntu server 16.04 LTS?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, router, dns

I am preparing ubuntu router with  2 interfaces

> enp2s0 (Connected to ISP WAN)
>
> enp2s8 (internal LAN network and DHCP server and DNS server)

my interface configuration (/etc/network/interfaces) is :

```
auto enp2s8
iface enp2s8 inet static
address 192.168.5.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.5.255



allow-hotplug enp2s0
auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet static
address 192.168.5.111
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.5.5
dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

`route` gives:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use      Iface
default         192.168.5.5     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0     enp2s0
192.168.5.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp2s0
192.168.5.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp2s8
```

`ip route` gives:

```
default via 192.168.5.5 dev enp2s0 onlink 
192.168.5.0/24 dev enp2s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.5.111 
192.168.5.0/24 dev enp2s8  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.5.1 linkdown
```

I can't access Internet from interface **enp2s8**.`ping -I enp2s8 google.com`  gives:

```
PING google.com (202.51.65.52) from 192.168.5.1 enp2s8: 56(84) bytes of data.
From olerouter.olenepal.local (192.168.5.1) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From olerouter.olenepal.local (192.168.5.1) icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From olerouter.olenepal.local (192.168.5.1) icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From olerouter.olenepal.local (192.168.5.1) icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From olerouter.olenepal.local (192.168.5.1) icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From olerouter.olenepal.local (192.168.5.1) icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
From olerouter.olenepal.local (192.168.5.1) icmp_seq=7 Destination Host Unreachable
```

but `ping -I enp2s0 google.com`  outputs:

```
PING google.com (202.51.67.32) from 192.168.5.111 enp2s0: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from cache.google.com (202.51.67.32): icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=1.45 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (202.51.67.32): icmp_seq=2 ttl=59 time=1.32 ms
```

I am new to UFW and not being able to Forward the IP between interfaces. Thanks in advance

Comment: Looking at your IP configuration, you don't want to forward packets (layer 3 routing), but you want to forward frames (layer 2 bridging). Your computer wouldn't be able to tell the difference between the two interfaces if you use the same subnet.

Comment: @mtak currently i have configured enp2s0 for my router with subnet /24 but in actual it will be connected to ISP's subnet of /25. do you mean i wont have any issuse if i switch to ISP's subnet?

Answer (score 0):

By obfuscating the real IP addresses and using the same `192.168.5.0/24` network both on `enp2s8` and `enp2s0` makes your question bit confusing. However, once you configure correct network on `enp2s0`, enable IPv4 forwarding(`sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`) and configure SNAT(source IP on packets from your `192.168.5.0/24` network needs to be changed to publicly routable IP address configured on `enp2s0`) with `iptables`, then you are ready to go.

Comment: thanks that helped..i set up with actual ISP subnet in enp2s0 and it worked